# If I scanned my QR Code once with my android phone from a paper wallet, but now it wont..Why

Tags: qrcode

I can no longer scan QR code from my paper wallet that I purchased from kiosk atm machine. I was able to scan it once, now the paper wallet has smears, rubbed off sections, etc. The kiosk machine's paper type resembles that of the slick paper used in an old fax machine and toner that smeared, smudged, etc just handling it a handful of times. Well, now I can only read by sight and a magnifying glass-all but 6/7 characters of the private key. I was able to make out the public address.
My thoughts are is it possible that my phone kept a copy of that one scan? If so, where & could I utilize it to gain access to move my bitcoin from paper wallet to my mobile wallet?

Comment: *"I was able to scan it once"* - with what did you scan it? A wallet app? Do you still have that app on your phone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My bitcoin atm purchased paper wallet QR code & private key is not working from paper wallet to mobile wallet... why](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/116624/my-bitcoin-atm-purchased-paper-wallet-qr-code-private-key-is-not-working-from)

Comment: I scanned it once just with my andriod ... no specific app. Even worse, I had to get an entire new phone..I could read the screen at all.

Comment: You used your phone's default camera app then? We can't give you a definite answer without knowing details to your device and Android version used. If you used a specific QR code scanner, s.a. Google Lens, there will most likely be some sort of history.

Comment: No app. Just samsung galaxy a21...which I had to replace with new phone since screen became unreadable...bunch of colored lines was all it would shhow.