# Why does an Android app show my address balance is zero on public servers but expected value on Jpm servers?

Tags: balance, android

My bitcoin address (public address ) & value has been checked for valid address / value amount on the "BITCOIN QR CODE READER" app with public servers used within the app on my Samsung galaxy A21 android device.

However, when I went confirm the same info, on same app, on same  device, but this time using public server option again; address validates but value amount, says zero.

Furthermore,  when I choose Jpm servers...BAM! It's showing valid address and validates value amount is correct.

What's happened & why is this?

p.s. the bitcoin address info etc, I purchased from a bitcoin kiosk atm. Which I am still having issues with reading it to get the correct private key

Comment: Does "addy" mean address? What is Jpm? What software are you using? In what way is what you're seeing not as expected? Please update your question with more information and details about what is going on.

Comment: I have the app BITCOIN QR CODE READER. You input the bitcoin address and check to make sure address is a valid BTC/BSV etc. It also shows the BTC value.

Comment: You have the option to use public servers or to use Jpm servers to do the validation/check

Comment: When providing extra information, It is usually better to edit your question (using that "edit" link underneath it) rather than only including the extra information in a comment. That way more people may read the details (some might skip over comments) and answer it.  I have edited your question for you (you can undo this if you don't like the changes, click on the "edited" link to undo or rollback a change).

Comment: Thank you, RedGrittyBrick. I am new, so any added knowledge is appreciated more than you can imagine!

Answer (score 1):

> I have the app BITCOIN QR CODE READER.

The nearest Android app I can [find with a search](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=BITCOIN%20QR%20CODE%20READER&c=apps&hl=en&gl=US) is "[Bitcoin QR Scanner Coin View](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coinviewer)" by Crypto Utilities. Or maybe you are instead using "QR-code scanner for Bitcoin BT" by Johan Meert?

It seems this sort of app lets you see the balance associated with an address but it does not give you any control over that balance. It does not give you ownership or the ability to spend that balance.

I would trust the answer given by a range of public servers much more than I would trust the answer given by one specific business. If answers diagree I would distrust the specific business and probably distrust the app.

Instead of using an app I would instead consult several [blockchain explorers](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer) directly using a standard web-browser. This will tell you if the app or your "Jpm servers" are giving false results.

Mostly I would rely on a [carefully-chosen](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet) independent [non-custodial wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866) to tell me the balance. But if you have a cold-wallet, it might make sense to use a set of well-known blockchain explorers or *reliable* app to check the balance at an address. I would probably prefer a carefully chosen non-custodial wallet in which I had imported the addresses (but not the keys) - a "watch-only" wallet.

---

> p.s. the bitcoin addy info etc, I purchased from a bitcoin kiosk atm. Which I am still having issues with reading it to get the correct private key

You refer to your earlier questions, one currently has an answer, the other is currently is waiting for you to respond to comments asking you to clarify the question:

- [My bitcoin atm purchased paper wallet QR code & private key is not working from paper wallet to mobile wallet... why](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/116624/13866)
- [If I scanned my QR Code once with my android phone from a paper wallet, but now it wont..Why](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/116633/13866)